# wxMaxima cannot detect maxima installation

Tags: installation, maxima

I recently installed Maxima (5.45.0-Windows) on my 64bit, windows 7 machine, following the [guide here](https://maxima.sourceforge.io/windows-install.html).
However, when I try to use the GUI, wxMaxima I get an error on launch, saying that the maxima.bat file could not be detected, and it suggests that Maxima was not properly installed. The error message in full is;

"Can not start Maxima. The most probable cause is that Maxima isn't installed (it can be downloaded from https://maxima.sourceforge.io) or in wxMaxima's config dialogue the setting for Maxima's location is wrong."

However, in the Edit-Configure-Maxima menu, under Maxima program I have the path `C:\maxima-5.45.0\bin\maxima.bat` which should be correct. In fact, when trying to run maxima commands through the command-line promp or through xmaxima, it works just fine.
The GUI however, fails to recognize my maxima.bat file, even when moving it to a different place and 'user specifying' the path, the GUI console is stuck on

```
Maxima Excited...
Restart Maxima with 'Maxima-Restart Maxima'
```

But trying to restart Maxima has no effect. Restarting the entire GUI program, or running it as administrator doesn't help either.

I've searched the web for this, but all the search results seem to concern Linux installations or a connection error wrt. internet, which doesn't seem to be my problem here.

Comment: Hi, debugging installation problems is often kind of hard. My advice is to copy your message to the Maxima mailing list, where it will get more attention and discussion. See: https://sourceforge.net/projects/maxima/lists/maxima-discuss

Comment: Same error here even with version 5.45.1. maxima.bat works fine from the command-line, Xmaxima, too. Except the help-system of Xmaxima. Firewall is not the problem, I switched it off, temporarily. I guess there is a internal problem with the slash and backslash handling.

Answer (score 0):

i have encountered the same issue (previous versions, now also 5.45.1 on windows 10). in my case this is resolved by manually deleting the "user config files" under %USERPROFILE%\maxima. these files are left over from the previous version & not removed by the un-installer.

try one of the following, then start wxmaxima again.

[command line] del %USERPROFILE%\maxima*.*

[explorer] C:\Users<your user ID>\maxima

Comment: That did not work for me.